# Managing multiple TCP Connections in active-mode from one GenServer

Tags: tcp, elixir

I generally use this pattern for interacting with a single TCP resource, in `active-mode`:

```
  def connect(ip, port) do
    t = System.system_time(1000)
    case :gen_tcp.connect(ip, port, [:binary, active: :once, keepalive: true, nodelay: true]) do
      {:ok, socket} ->
        log "Connected to #{ip}:#{port} in #{System.system_time(1000) - t}ms"
        socket
      {:error, err} ->
        log "Connect Error - #{ip}: #{port} [#{inspect err}]"
        Process.send_after(self(), :retry_connect, 3000)
        nil
    end
  end

  def handle_info({:tcp, _, data}, s) do
    s = proc_raw(s.extra <> data, %{s | extra: ""})

    :inet.setopts(s.socket, active: :once)

    {:noreply, s}
  end
```

How can this be extended to handle **multiple** TCP connections in the same `GenServer`?

So far this works great for a single TCP socket in `active-mode`

**Update**

Each GenServer is managed under a supervisor. Also, each GenServer represents one client, each client may have 3-5 TCP connections to some external resources.

Failure/Reset of the TCP connections is expected from time to time, a reconnect is tried on each failure, but the host GenServer need not restart

Comment: Why wouldn't you want one process per connection? It makes sense to isolate connections, as an individual connection might close, and should not affect the others.

Comment: Each GenServer is for a single client instance. Each Client Instance manages up to 5 tcp connections to same TCP resources

Comment: @MartinSvalin a closing or Failing TCP connection will be managed and restarted, it should not crash the process as it is an expected bebavior

Comment: I'd still use a supervision tree. Instead of one GenServer per client, I'd have one supervisor per client, and one GenServer per tcp connection. I think the failure handling would be easier to reason about that way.

Comment: @MartinSvalin hmm, i'll consider that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with @Onorio Catenacci that mulitple GenServers is probably a better way to go. However, I will still answer the question you asked.

The second position of the tuple passed to `handle_info` is the socket that is receiving data.  Thus, you already know which socket it is coming from.

```
handle_info({:tcp, socket, data}, s) do
  # do something with the socket here ... 
end
```

I would suspect the only other change necessary is keeping a reference to all open sockets, which can be done by modifying the `handle_call` for connect function and your GenServer's `init` function to be something like:

```
def init(_) do
  {:ok, []}
end

def handle_call({:connect, ip, port}, _from, sockets) do
  s = connect(ip, port)
  {:reply, :ok, [s|sockets]}
end
```

Note, you will probably need to also change your `handle_call` for :retry_connect function in a similar way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I hadn't realized that that the socket was also returned with `handle_info({:tcp, socket, data}, s)`

Comment: For a standalone mode, i currently use one named GenServer per connection. I'm looking to run multiple GenServers, then have each Genserver manage a few TCP connections. what @Onorio-Catenacci suggested would not be ideal in my scenario

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use a [Supervisor](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/supervisor-and-application.html) rather than a GenServer. A supervisor will allow you to automatically restart a failing connection among other things:

> When things fail, your first reaction may be: “let’s rescue those
>   errors”. But in Elixir we avoid the defensive programming habit of
>   rescuing exceptions, as commonly seen in other languages. Instead, we
>   say “let it crash”. If there is a bug that leads our registry to
>   crash, we have nothing to worry about because we are going to set up a
>   supervisor that will start a fresh copy of the registry.

I realize the above passage is discussing a "registry" but the concept is the same.

I also realize that my answer is somewhat generic.  However, since your question is also pretty generic, it's hard for me to give you something more specific. If you have a more specific question, I'd suggest you edit your question and we can give you more specific answers.

Comment: Each GenServer is Supervised

Comment: Ok, so then if each GenServer is supervised why do you want each GenServer to handle multiple connections?  Just fire up more GenServers.  I mean if there's some constraint on adding more GenServers then you need to add that to your question because it seems like you're trying to solve a non-existent problem.

Comment: I have updated the question with some context, giving the relationship between the GenServer and the Connections